# carousel can't get images div to the center

Tags: html, css, django-templates, carousel

i tried to make a carousel slide that auto fit image size but i can't get the div that contain the images to show up in the middle of the outer div( i tried to put text-align:center and margin-left: auto on every possible divs and still can't manage to make it center):

Here my html which is in my django template so ignore {% %} it just output my data to the template(include css style for testing so i can put in my css file later):

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-body" style="text-align: center;">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="height: 100%; cursor: pointer; display: table-row; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; border: 0px; text-align: center; height: 100%">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    {% for image in property.images %}
                    {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators3" data-slide-to="{{ forloop.counter0 }}" class="active"></li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators3" data-slide-to="{{ forloop.counter0 }}"></li>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    {% for image in property.images %}
                    {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ image }}" style="width: auto !important; height: auto; max-height: 100%; display: inline">
                    </div>
                    {% else %}
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ image }}" style="width: auto !important; height: auto; max-height: 100%;display: inline">
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators3" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators3" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I kinda stuck on this problem for a few days so any help would be nice!

Comment: Don't show us the if/else logic stuff, this does not really help us. It's better to show the HTML code how it lands in the browser, and also show accompaning CSS.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
body {
  background-image: url('w3css.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
```

from: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: it's not a background of a div , it carousel that contain images and which div should i use those css ?

Comment: just try and tell me the results.

Comment: i tried it in the body and the outisde div and it doesn't work